# Store List of user defined Expressions/Lambdas for type T

Tags: c#, lambda, func, linq-expressions

The objective here is to allow API consumers to register their model and how to extract data from that model.  Using the ValueMapper below we provide a CreateMap method that registers the map name and function to call to retrieve the data as an object.

The idea here being that certain model have a little more work to get the data out correctly. Once the model is registered using CreateMap we'll store that in an internal list/dictionary for future look ups. I've tried a few different angles to solve this problem and this is very close but still is lacking since the caller cannot provide actual expression logic then can only return a straight value.

I've stripped down the code to the bare bones and if there's a better way to solve my problem i'm open to suggestions.

```
// static class that I would like to hold a list of 'expressions' that can be looked up and executed multuples times by the run time logic
public static class ValueMapper
{
    private static Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> _rules = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

    public static void CreateMap<T>(string ruleName, Expression<Func<T, object>> valueExpression)
    {
        _rules.Add(ruleName, valueExpression);
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        // This works but doesn't allow for registering further logic
        ValueMapper.CreateMap<ExternalUser>("foo", user => user.FirstName);

        // This has a compiler error as follows : "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"
        ValueMapper.CreateMap<ExternalUser>("foo", user =>
        {
            return user.FirstName + user.LastName;
        });
    }
}

// some external class
public class ExternalUser
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but doesn't allow for registering further logic" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: You don't need a statement lambda to return the first name plus the last name, just do that in an expression lambda.

Comment: And also, do you need expressions really? What are you going to do with them? Maybe just delegate (Func) will do?

Comment: What you're trying to do sounds over-engineered and would be very difficult to maintain. One giveaway is that it's not strongly typed. Someone has to call something and get an `object`, and then go read code somewhere else to figure out what that object is. There's a strong chance of runtime errors that should be the sort of thing the compiler catches.

Comment: Also, instead of calling functions by... calling functions, consumers would have to invoke them using strings. The compiler will help you if someone changes or removes a method. You can tell what's broken right away. But if your method call is something like `var firstName = (string)ValueMapper.InvokeRule<ExternalUser>(ExternalUser input, "foo");` then the compiler won't help you if someone changes "foo". You won't even get intellisense to help you.

Comment: @Evk, could you provide a sample please.  i'm not fixed on any particular path.  I would like to folks that interactive with the Api to be register their function with strong type.

Comment: @Mike please show how exactly are you going to _use_ functions stored in `_rules` dictionary (with some code).

Comment: @Scott, this isn't a public facing api. This is a way we can map how EntityX should return it's data to us.  The naming convention we us will not be a problem for looking these up during run time.

Comment: @Evk, i'm not sure, that's part of my question.  If you've every used AutoMapper for example. They allow you to CreateMaps<T>(Func<T etc etc)  .  Something similar to that is what were looking for.    eg:  User has a Type that needs different "extraction rules" applied.  The Register/Map this type by calling a method.. They then provide us with a function that will correct extra the data.

Comment: And what role rule name plays here?

Comment: Rule name is an internal name well use to lookup and see if there's an entry for the currently executing  object. If theres an entry then we'll pass the instance object to the function so it can execute it.

Comment: And each type has unique mapping (only one rule per type)?

Comment: Only types that are problematic. Other types will have no rules and just get handled outside of this

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it seems you don't need expressions, simple delegates should do:

```
public static class ValueMapper {
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>> _rules = new Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>>();

    public static void CreateMap<T>(string ruleName, Func<T, object> valueFunc) {
        _rules.Add(ruleName, c => valueFunc((T) c));
    }
}
```

If there is only one mapping per target type - no need to use strings, use types:

```
public static class ValueMapper {
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _rules = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public static void CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>(Func<TFrom, TTo> valueFunc) {
        _rules.Add(typeof(TFrom), c => valueFunc((TFrom)c));
    }

    public static object Map<T>(T instance) {
        if (_rules.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            return _rules[typeof(T)](instance);
        // or throw here, or return null, depending on what you need
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If you know types you are mapping to - use them:

```
public static class ValueMapper {
    private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> _rules = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public static void CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>(Func<TFrom, TTo> valueFunc) {
        _rules.Add(typeof(TFrom), c => valueFunc((TFrom)c));
    }

    public static TTo Map<TTo>(object instance) {
        if (_rules.ContainsKey(instance.GetType()))
            return (TTo) _rules[instance.GetType()](instance);
        // throw here if necessary 
        return default(TTo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great examples and explanation, exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks.